# Retrieving the Phone number from a contact using "ContactsContract" by an ID?

Tags: android, contactscontract

I'm able to retrieve the display name of contact using the id Code as follows:

```
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, selectedid);
Cursor cur = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);
startManagingCursor(cur);
cur.moveToNext();
String mname = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
```

Where the "selectedid" is my id of the contact to be retrieved.
Now i have a problem in retrieving the phone number from that id.

If possible can u type me the code which i have to add to get the phone number from that id

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve Contact Phone Number From URI in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370628/retrieve-contact-phone-number-from-uri-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i kind of figured it out .... try the link bellow...

> [Retrieve Contact Phone Number From URI in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370628/retrieve-contact-phone-number-from-uri-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
String number = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
```

Comment: i have tried it and got a error stating.....    "02-08 14:18:42.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(415): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.kpj4s.as/com.kpj4s.as.activity_newsms}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed"