# Retrieving phone number from contact id : android

Tags: android, contacts

I'm trying to get contact data once a contact name has been clicked from my list view. As per the code below, I can log successfully the ID of my contact, but haven't managed to use the ContactsContract to retrieve the data. What's the best way to do this? (have tried [Retrieve Contact Phone Number From URI in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370628/retrieve-contact-phone-number-from-uri-in-android) to not much avail)

EDIT 2 : Fixed code, now works

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "Activity State: onCreate()");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact_manager);
        mContactList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactList);
        populateContactList();

        mContactList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            String strid = Long.toString(id);               
            Cursor result = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.Contacts._ID +" = ?", new String[]{strid}, null);
            if (result.moveToFirst()) { 
                 Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
                          new String[] {Data._ID, Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE, Phone.LABEL},
                          Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND "
                                  + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
                          new String[] {String.valueOf(strid)}, null);
                 if(c.moveToFirst()){
                     int phoneColumn = c.getColumnIndex("data1");
                     String phoneNumber = c.getString(phoneColumn);
                     Log.d("DATA",phoneNumber);
                 }
            }
        });
    }
```

EDIT 1 : forgot some important stuff. The code is adapted from the ContactManager example from the Android dev site.

```
/**
 * Populate the contact list based on account currently selected in the account spinner.
 */
private void populateContactList() {
    // Build adapter with contact entries
    Cursor cursor = getContacts();
    String[] fields = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME
    };
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_entry, cursor,
            fields, new int[] {R.id.contactEntryText});
    mContactList.setAdapter(adapter);
}

/**
 * Obtains the contact list for the currently selected account.
 *
 * @return A cursor for for accessing the contact list.
 */
private Cursor getContacts()
{
    // Run query
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
    };
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
}
```

Comment: So what from that question have you tried?

Comment: How did you store the ID in your list? Are the ID in the Contact table? RawCOntact table? Can you post the code for populateContactList?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a valid contactID, you can do this:

```
Cursor result = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, 
         ContactsContract.Contacts._ID +" = ?", 
         new String[]{contactID}, null);      
if (result.moveToFirst()) {

    for(int i=0; i< result.getColumnCount(); i++){
        Log.i("CONTACTSTAG", result.getColumnName(i) + ": "
        + result.getString(i));
    }         
}
```

You will have to change the ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI and the where clause to the table that you are querying. The above code will print out a bunch of general info about a contact.

Comment: hey thanks! From there I was able to query the data table and find what I needed. Updated code with new query.