# How to get Specific Contact Number by using Contact Id

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-cursor

Here my Contact names are Displayed on List View . By clicking the List I get `ContactName` and `Contact Id`. From that I want to fetch`Phone number` by Using either `Contact ID` or `Contact name`,Please Help me.

Here is My Code

```
void ReadContacts(String sort) {
    final Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    final String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
    };
    //boolean mShowInvisible = false;
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '1'";
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    final String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    m_curContacts = managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    String[] fields = new String[] {ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME};
    m_slvAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                m_curContacts,
                fields, 
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
    m_slvAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {

        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "runQuery constraint:"+constraint);
            String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '1'" +
                    " AND "+ ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE '%"+constraint+"%'";
            String[] selectionArgs = null;//new String[]{"'1'"};//, };
            Cursor cur = managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
            return cur;
        }

   });
   m_lvContacts.setAdapter(m_slvAdapter); 
   //  cur.close();

}



public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
    ContentResolver cr;
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) m_lvContacts.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String szDisplayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    String szId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    int nId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Item click:"+position+" szId:"+szId+" nId:"+nId+" Data:"+szDisplayName);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item click:"+phoneNumber+" szId:"+szId+" nId:"+nId+" Data:"+szDisplayName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370628/retrieve-contact-phone-number-from-uri-in-android

Comment: i used the above link but phoneindex produce o value

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044545/get-contact-info-from-android-contact-picker.Please try to search on SO.Such questions have already asked and you have to just arrange it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this one

```
ArrayList<String> phones = new ArrayList<String>();

Cursor cursor = mContentResolver.query(
        CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
        null, 
        CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
        new String[]{id}, null);

while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
{
    phones.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
} 

cursor.close();
return(phones);
```

Comment: i dont want list of phone number i need a particular number

Comment: Have u checked? I think It return only one number

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
public void getNameUsingContactId(String contactId){

    String cContactIdString = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
    Uri cCONTACT_CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String cDisplayNameColumn = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;

    String selection = cContactIdString + " = ? ";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId)};

    Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(cCONTACT_CONTENT_URI, null, selection, selectionArgs, null);
    if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.getCount() > 0)) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while ((cursor != null) && (cursor.isAfterLast() == false)) {
            if (cursor.getColumnIndex(cContactIdString) >= 0) {
                if (contactId.equals(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cContactIdString)))) {
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cDisplayNameColumn));
                     break;
                }
            }
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.close();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the phonenumbers in the data table. Find the corresponding raw contact ids in the rawcontacts table (use contact ID as where criteria), use these raw contact ids to query the data table. The phonenumber will have a certain mime type (away from the docs now) so you can recognize them.
Hope this helps!

Tips: copy the contacts2.db database from your emulator/device and use Squirrel (SQLite jdbc driver) to poke around in the contacts database. The db is located under /data/data/ look for contacts in the list).

Answer (score 0):

Guys I got the Answer:

Please Use this Code if you need:

```
  Cursor cursor = (Cursor) m_lvContacts.getItemAtPosition(position);
        String szDisplayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String szId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        int nId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
         long l = Long.parseLong(szId);
        int type=ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE;




 cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
         null,
         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID+"='"+szId+"'",
         null, null);

            int phoneNumberIndex = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));

            if (cursor != null) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Cursor Not null");
                try {
                    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "Moved to first");
                        Log.v(TAG, "Cursor Moved to first and checking");
                        phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneNumberIndex);
                        System.out.println("HAGSd"+phoneNumber);
                    }
                } finally {
                    Log.v(TAG, "In finally");
                    cursor.close();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String contactIdByPhoneNumber(Context ctx, String phoneNumber) {
    String contactId = null;
    if (phoneNumber != null && phoneNumber.length() > 0) {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = ctx.getContentResolver();

        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));

        String[] projection = new String[] { PhoneLookup._ID };

        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhoneLookup._ID));
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return contactId;
}
```