# Get contact in android using data table content://com.android.contacts/data/1319

Tags: android, android-contacts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieve Contact Phone Number From URI in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370628/retrieve-contact-phone-number-from-uri-in-android)

I have content provider Uri `content://com.android.contacts/data/1319` . can i get phone number corresponding to this uri.

- I found some thing for This, i.e I can get `raw_Contact_id` from this, With `raw_contact_id` i can get `contact_id`, now please can any one tell me how can I join all these `data`, `contacts` and `raw_contacts` table to get `phone number`.

Comment: yes, you can (at least if this contact has phone number) ... what have you tried so far ? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html

Comment: Thanks for comment Sevin, I will get the above as intent data when I click on connection of particular contact. I want to use that number in the activity which is launched on clicking connection.

Comment: I asked a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370628/retrieve-contact-phone-number-from-uri-in-android

Comment: I gone thro` your ans  hwrdprkns , but I will get error when I execute the code like yours.

Comment: As hwrdprkns said I got solution from [hwrdprkns's ans][1]. Thanks hwrdprkns


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370628/retrieve-contact-phone-number-from-uri-in-android